# Azure-Functions: How to serve content from the root of domain

Tags: azure, configuration, azure-functions

Is there any way to serve content out of a root of the domain with an azure function without using a proxy?

I defined a function with a route of / and it appears to be ignored.

I've found a way to use the Proxies (beta), to serve content from the root, but this doesn't work for local development (Proxies appear to only be on Azure, not in the azure-functions-cli).

In various issues I've found a few cryptic references indicating it may be possible, or was possible at one time, but haven't figured out how to.

Comment: Check out my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67866981/6908282

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you're asking for, but my approach would be to use fiddler to emulate Proxies locally.

You can add the following to FiddlerScript:

```
OnBeforeRequest(oSession: Session) {
...
    if (oSession.host == "127.0.0.1:5050" && oSession.PathAndQuery == "/") {
        oSession.PathAndQuery = "/content";
    }
...
}
```

This will catch any requests to localhost `127.0.0.1` at the specified port `5050` with root path `/` and redirect to `/content` path. You'll need to modify this for your specific port and path.

I'd also encourage you to file an issue on the [azure functions cli github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-cli)