# Azure Functions: serving content for root URL

Tags: azure-functions

I have an C# Azure Function project, with a variety of functions.

One of the functions is to serve some HTML content. This function can currently be accessed at /api/home. However, I want to have it triggered for the root / URL.

I have added a proxies.json file in my project:

```
{
  "Home": {
    "matchCondition": {
      "methods": ["GET"],
      "route": "/"
    },
    "backendUri": "https://localhost:7071/api/home"
  }
}
```

But this still has no effect - it continues to serve up the default Azure Fucntions webpage.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 7):

**A Better Solution for Azure Functions V4.**

**tl;dr** It turns out you *can* set a function route to "/". You just need the right settings.

As others have noted, proxies were disabled in v4. And then [added back](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/legacy-proxies#re-enable-proxies-in-functions-v4x) but they are still deprecated. Microsoft recommends using Azure API Management but that's way too complicated for just this use case.

This solution, which is backward compatible with V3, I got from an [excellent blog post by Julian Hüppauff](https://blog.hueppauff.com/Post/Azure-Functions-v4---Provide-a-Function-at-the-content-root-url).

First, (this was the missing piece for me) you have to turn off the default Azure Functions homepage. You do this in your application settings. You must set `AzureWebJobsDisableHomepage` to `true`. On the Azure host you do this in [Azure Functions Application Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings?tabs=portal#settings).

On your local machine, for testing, you add the setting to `local.settings.json` like this.

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsDisableHomepage": "true"
  }
}
```

Next, as @Gangula mentioned, you turn off the default "/api" prefix to your functions. Add `routePrefix` to your `host.json` as follows:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "http": {
      "routePrefix": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, create a function with `Route = "/"`. You can do whatever you want in that function - serve default text, 301 redirect to a different url, etc.

I hope this helps people coming to this problem post V4!

Comment: Although I was seeing `Executing 'Functions.MyFunction' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.')` the function would never actually execute. I'm not sure where it's getting stuck but using a slightly modified route did the trick to actually run the function: `public async Task RunAsync([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "{*ignored}")] FunctionContext context, string ignored = "")`

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid you can't use the root path to access this function, because `https://localhost:7071/` is always the default page of Azure function:

[image]

Below are my verification steps, I will change the path of the function to `https://localhost:7071/`, but it still displays the default page of `Azure function app`.

By default, the route for your azure function would be `localhost:7071/api/{functionName}`

You must have noticed by now that almost all the function routes had `/api/` in the route. In case, you wanted to change it, you can change it by modifying the content using the `host.json`.

You need to add `"extensions": { "http": { "routePrefix": "" } }` in your host.json:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensions": { "http": { "routePrefix": "" } }
}
```

Now, your route might look like this:

```
localhost:7071/{functionName}
```

You also need to set the `Route` in the code to `""`.

```
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = "")] HttpRequest req,
```

[image]

The current route should meet your requirements：

[image]

**But using this path to access this function still fails, so I think it is invalid to set the path of the Azure function as the root path, and you cannot use it to access your Azure function.**

If you deploy to `Azure portal`, you can try to add `"AzureWebJobsDisableHomepage ": true` in `app settings` to disable the homepage of Azure function. I tested it locally and it doesn't seem to work. `Azure portal` seems to work.

Comment: Even though I am late to the Party, but an addition here. Setting the Route to "/" seems to solve it. This way you can set a function to the route of the website. But, it is displayed incorrectly in the console "http://localhost:7071//" but "http://localhost:7071/" works just fine

Comment: I'm proxying a storage account. When I build my go binary & test all works fine but not with the functions. I removed the `api` & `function-name` from the url with your instructions but somehow the request fails with 404. Don't know what I'm missing.

Answer (score 4):

## EDIT Feb 12, 2024

Looks like below mentioned approach is not valid - especially since proxies are deprecated since Functions v4.

Checkout [@bredd's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76419027/6908282) for a better approach which is backward compatible.

---

## Jun 07, 2021

You can [add a Proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies#advanced-configuration) in the `proxies.json` file to a selected function and re-direct it to the root url like below

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
  "proxies": {
    "Proxy1": {
      "matchCondition": {
        "route": "/"
      },
      "backendUri": "https://<AnotherApp>.azurewebsites.net/api/<FunctionName>"
    }
  }
}
```

This will redirect all the calls to the rool URL to the function with name "`<FunctionName>`"

---

## Bonus Tip:

If you'd like to remove `/api` from your URL, you can do so by adding the following code in `host.json` file

```
  "extensions": {
     "http": { 
       "routePrefix": "" 
       } 
    }
```

Comment: According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies) page, proxies are only supported in Azure Functions 1.x through 3.x. This apparently means that they are not supported in Azure Functions 4.x. If I add a proxies.json to my 4.x Azure Function locally I unfortunately get an error message indicating that proxies are not supported in 4.x.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this @JonTurner. According to docs its [recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions?tabs=azure-cli%2Cin-process%2Cv4&pivots=programming-language-csharp#runtime) to use "API Management" from v4.x. You can find more details & comparison [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/azure-functions-v4-versus-v3/ba-p/3276055). But there is [no migration guide](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/2165) as of now which mentions how to replicate the proxies in v4.x.

Comment: [Proxies can now be reenabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/legacy-proxies#re-enable-proxies-in-functions-v4x) in Functions v4

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about `matchConditions` but setting `route` to `/` works for me in v4 Functions (Node):

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "route": "/",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I see below error on v4 functions (golang) with this config.. 
`The route template separator character '/' cannot appear consecutively. It must be separated by either a parameter or a literal value.`